# Problem with making explicit formula from recursive formula

Tags: sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations

I'm having trouble turning this recursive formula into explicit one

$a_0 = 0,\\a_{n+1} = a_n(1 - b_n) + b_n,$

where $(b_n)$ is given sequence of real numbers.

Comment: Have you tried writing out the first few terms? $a_1 = b_0$, $a_2 = b_0(1-b_1) + b_1 = b_0 + b_1 - b_0b_1$ etc. Use some computer algebra package, maybe?

Comment: I've tried, but it's hard (at least for me) to find a pattern. The size of formula grows exponentially. Computer algebra package? Could you recommend any?

Comment: Maple, Mathlab, Mathematica. Online maybe Wolfram alpha?

Comment: @jr_ $$\begin{align*}
a_{n+1}-1=&a_n(1-b_n)-1+b_n\\=&(a_n-1)(1-b_n)\\
a_0-1=&-1\end{align*}$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since
$$\begin{align*}
a_{n+1}-1=&a_n(1-b_n)-1+b_n\\=&(a_n-1)(1-b_n)\end{align*}$$

Consider instead a sequence $(c_n)$, $c_n=a_n-1$, $n=0,1,2,\ldots$,

$$\begin{align*}
a_n-1=c_n=&c_{n-1}(1-b_{n-1})\\
=&c_{n-2}(1-b_{n-2})(1-b_{n-1})\\
=&c_{n-3}(1-b_{n-3})(1-b_{n-2})(1-b_{n-1})\\
&\vdots\\
=&c_{n-n}\prod_{i=1}^{n}(1-b_{n-i})\\
=&c_0\prod_{j=0}^{n-1}(1-b_j)\\
=&-\prod_{j=0}^{n-1}(1-b_j)\\
a_n=&1-\prod_{j=0}^{n-1}(1-b_j)
\end{align*}$$